Adding values to a dataframe based on lookup in the same dataframe
I try to get my head around a solution for a lookup and filling of an additional column in a pandas dataframe for readability.
The following data (truncated) is available where manager_id is filled with the corresponding user_ids



last_name
first_name
user_id
manager_id




scorsese
martin
1
2


wenders
wim
2
2


kurosawa
akira
3
3


sabu
sabu
4
3



the outcome should be:



last_name
first_name
user_id
manager_id
manager_name




scorsese
martin
1
2
wim wenders


wenders
wim
2
2
wim wenders


kurosawa
akira
3
3
akira kurosawa


sabu
sabu
4
3
akira kurosawa



So far I have been struggeling to find a concise and nice solution with only pandas based methods. I have a working solution but it is a dirty hack iterating through a dictionary of the same dataframe and looking up the row index based on name etc. Very ugly.
    dictionary_of_kantoku = df_kantoku.to_dict(orient="records")
    for kantoku in dictionary_of_kantoku:
        row_index = df_kantoku.loc[
            (df_kantoku['last_name'].str.contains(kantoku['last_name'])
             & df_kantoku['first_name'].str.contains(kantoku['first_name']))].index[0]
        manager_id = df_kantoku[(df_kantoku['last_name'].str.contains(kantoku['last_name'])
             & df_kantoku['first_name'].str.contains(kantoku['first_name']))]['manager_id'].values[0]
        manager_name = df_kantoku[df_kantoku['user_id'] == manager_id]['first_name'].values[0] + ' ' + df_kantoku[df_kantoku['user_id'] == manager_id]['last_name'].values[0]
        if row_index != 0:
            resultset.loc[row_index, 'manager_name'] = manager_name

Can someone please shed some light how this can be done efficiently without the dictionary hack and the iterating?
Thanks a lot.

You can simply do this
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'last_name': ['Scorsese', 'Wenders', 'Kurosawa', 'Sabu'],
    'first_name': ['Martin', 'Wim', 'Akira', 'Sabu'],
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'manager_id': [2, 2, 3, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

name_map = df.set_index('user_id')['first_name'] + ' ' + df.set_index('user_id')['last_name']
df['manager_name'] = df['manager_id'].map(name_map)

print(df)


which gives
 last_name first_name  user_id  manager_id    manager_name
0  Scorsese     Martin        1           2     Wim Wenders
1   Wenders        Wim        2           2     Wim Wenders
2  Kurosawa      Akira        3           3  Akira Kurosawa
3      Sabu       Sabu        4           3  Akira Kurosawa
[ ]




Wow! Very nice, thats the difference between professional and hobbyist! Thanks a lot.

import pandas as pd
raw_data = [["scorsese", "martin", "1", "2", "wim wenders "], 
            ["wenders", "wim", "2", "2", "wim wenders "], 
            ["kurosawa", "akira", "3", "3", "akira kurosawa "], 
            ["sabu", "sabu", "4", "3", "akira kurosawa "]]


last_name ,first_name ,user_id ,manager_id ,manager_name   = list(map(list, zip(*raw_data)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"last_name":last_name ,"first_name":first_name ,"user_id":user_id, "manager_id": manager_id})
df["manager_name"] = manager_name

